# Templating two XML files

Tags: c#, xml, merge, templating

I'm trying to merge two XML documents. The first one is a kind of template with default values, and the second one has the same structure with missing fields.
I would like to load both files and fill missing fields of the second XML file with default values given in the first file.
For example :

DefaultConfig.xml :

```
<CollectionItem>
   <Item>
      <var1>10</var1>
      <var2>20</var2>
   </Item>
</CollectionItem>
```

Config1.xml :

```
<CollectionItem>
   <Item>
      <var1>5</var1>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <var2>5</var2>
   </Item>
</CollectionItem>
```

As a result, I'd like the output file to look like :

```
<CollectionItem>
   <Item>
      <var1>5</var1>
      <var2>20</var2>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <var1>10</var>
      <var2>5</var2>
   </Item>
</CollectionItem>
```

Furthermore, I'd like to be generic, if I add a field in the node Item, I don't want to code it but rather read it in the default XML file.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the XML files using the [XElemnt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) class.
you get the child elements using the method Elements().
each element has a property "name".
if the non-default element doesn't have a field that the default element has - add it with the Add function.

at the end don't forget to call the function "save".

Comment: Ok, that's the easiest way, I was looking for a more "automatic" way with something like a SQL request ... but thank you, that was indeed my first draft ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, simple approch, I just wondered if there were not already a method to do it. I know the merge function of two datasets with can merge the structure with attributes "converted" to an element or an element to an attribute following a gicen scheme....

And to go further, what if the two files are juste one file like that :

```
<CollectionItem>
   <Item>
      <Name>default</Name>
      <var1>5</var1>
      <var2>20</var2>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>config1</Name>
      <var1>10</var>
   </Item>
</CollectionItem>
```

and while deserialization into a class "CollectionItem", I'd like to populate the second Item with its values plus the default values that I find in the first Item if not given ? It is quite simple to do it after deserialization, but is it possible possible to do it AT deserialization. With binary files it is also easy with the interface IOnDeseralizationCallback, but this concept does not exist with XML files...